# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Razor View: filter parent elements by distinct child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am struggeling with a razor view that has a hierarchical structure of **Products** and **Parts**.

A Product can contain **multiple** Parts.

In my view I pass a list of products.

Now in a table I only want to show **distinct** parts so that duplicate parts and products are removed.

Example:

[image]

So based on above example, only a single product (first in the image but first or last does not matter) should be picked, so that a part is only shown once even if multiple products contain this part.

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    foreach (var part in product.parts)
    {
    }
}
```

These two loops output distinct products so I believe somewhere in those two loops the logic needs to be implemented in order to achieve above target.

And that's where I hope you can help me with. Can it be done with Linq, do I need to create helper variables, etc.?

Thank you.

Comment: You should go back to your query and build an appropriate viewmodel there. Query all parts, which have one or more products, group by the part name and take the first of each group. That should give you what you need.

Comment: I thought about that too. But there are quite a lot of dependencies in that Product ViewModel that makes it difficult to rebuild. So I am hoping for some "hack" inside the view :-)

Comment: You are trying to fix a wrong view model, by using additional logic. This just creates overhead. Fix the model and the underlying business logic and keep your view simple.  If you have to implement a second client, you'd end up copying over this additional code, instead of just causing the root problem of it.